# Crear prototipos para aplicaciones Android

Tags: android, prototipos

estoy interesado en optar por una herramienta que me sea bastante util para poder realizar ***prototipos de aplicaciones móviles***, especificamente para Android. Empece buscando alguna en la web, pero como comprenderán existen muchas, es por eso que me interesaría saber de su opinión y que me pudieran recomendar alguna de ellas en base a su experiencia en desarrollo. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3):

En internet puedes encontrar varias opciones para realizar diseños prototipo para mobiles, agrego algunos que podrían interesarte y al menos alguna vez he usado.

- Invision:
  https://www.invisionapp.com/
- Marvel
  https://marvelapp.com/
- Balsamiq (el primero que use!).
  https://balsamiq.com/
- Proto.io
  https://proto.io/
- Atomic.io
  https://atomic.io/
- Fluid UI
  https://www.fluidui.com/
- Nockingbot
  https://mockingbot.com/

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys, hay mucho que revisar con esto.

Comment: Perfecto @BrandoT, saludos!.

Answer (score 1):

Si eres usuario de Mac, te recomiendo que pruebes [Adobe XD](http://www.adobe.com/es/products/experience-design.html) está en fase preview y por el momento es gratis, yo la estoy usando y es muy completa si quieres crear tus diseños y hacer el prototipado en la misma app.

Answer (score 0):

Una buena opción es [invision](https://www.invisionapp.com/) y si quieres tienen [curso gratuito en Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/rapid-prototyping--ud723).

Como opinión y basado en la experiencia me parece que lo importante es que se pueda enviar al cliente el prototipo para que puedan comentarlo y acumular esas notas para llegar hasta lo que realmente necesitaba desarrollar.

Comment: Perfecto gracias @tinoper